# Why is BeautifulSoup(...).find(...) returning None?

Tags: python

I have some problem with code (I use bs4):

```
elif 'temperature' in query:
        speak("where?")
        miejsce=takecommand().lower()
        search = (f"Temperature in  {miejsce}")
        url = (f'https://www.google.com/search?q={search}')
        r = requests.get(url)
        data = BeautifulSoup(r.text , "html.parser")
        temp = data.find("div", class_="BNeawe").text
        speak(f"In {search} there is {temp}")
```

and the error is:

```
temp = data.find("div", class_="BNeawe").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Could you help me please

Comment: You wrote some code that runs against the result of a dynamic search. The thing that popped up on your search 2 days ago isn't guaranteed to be there each time.

Comment: Try to print response text.

Comment: It did not find the `div` tag that was there 2 days ago. This is the reason of the error

Comment: From the error it seems like the website has changed, meaning maybe the class name has changed since nothing is being returned. I suggest you go through the html file again or give us the full code so that we can do it

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to use directly api google / weather - If you wanna scrape,try to avoid selecting your elements by classes, cause they are often that dynamic.

Instead focus on `id` if possible or use HTML structure:

```
for p in list(soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("weather.com")').parents):
    if '°' in p.text:
        print(p.next.get_text(strip=True))
        break
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=temperature"
response = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5'}, cookies={'CONSENT':'YES+'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

for p in list(soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("weather.com")').parents):
    if '°' in p.text:
        print(p.next.get_text(strip=True))
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.find("div", class_="BNeawe")` didnt return anything, so i believe google changed how it displays weather since you last ran this code successfully.

If you search for yourself 'Weather in {place}' then right click the weather widget and choose `Inspect Element` (browser dependent), you can look for yourself at where the data is in the page, and see which class the data is under.

It appears it was previously under the `BNeawe` class.

Comment: This is what i found:  '<span class="wob_t TVtOme" id="wob_tm" style="display:inline">19</span>'  but any class doesn't work

Comment: Did you try instead with `temp = data.find("div", class_="TVtOme").text`? I am assuming you want the temperature from this page?

Comment: Yes I did. I got the same error. Yes I want the temperature

Comment: Ok I just ran almost an exact replica of your code on replit.com using `temp = data.find("div", class_="BNeawe").text` and it is working fine for me. I don't know how I can help you. There must be something you are missing. There could be an error with your request object `r` or the data that is returned. Add to your code `print(r)` and `print(data)` and see if anything looks off

Answer (score 0):

```
elif "temperature" in query or "temperatures" in query:
    search = "Temperature in New York"
    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={search}:"
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    temp = data.find("div", class_="BNeawe").text
    speak(f"Currently, the temperature in your region is {temp}")
```

Try this one, you were experiencing your proble in line 5 which is '(r.text, "html.parser")'
try to avoid these comma space mistakes in the code...